# Websockets and uwsgi - detect broken connections client side?

Tags: websocket, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi's websockets support and so far it's looking great, the server detects when the client disconnects and the client as well when the server goes down. But i'm concerned this will not work in every case/browser.

In other frameworks, namely sockjs, the connection is monitored by sending regular messages that work as heartbeats/pings. But uwsgi sends PING/PONG frames (ie. not regular messages/control frames) according to the websockets spec and so from the client side i have no way to know when the last ping was received from the server. So my question is this:

If the connection is dropped or blocked by some proxy will browsers reliably (ie. Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera) detect no PING was received from the server and signal the connection as down or should i implement some additional ping/pong system so that the connection is detected as closed from the client side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although browsers that implement the same RFC as uWSGI should detect reliably when the server closes the connection cleanly they won't detect when the connection is interrupted midway ([half open connections](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html))t. So from what i understand we should employ an extra mechanism like application level pings.

Answer (score 2):

You are totally right. There is no way from client side to track or send ping/pongs. So if the connection drops, the server is able of detecting this condition through the ping/pong, but the client is let hung... until it tries to send something and the underlying TCP mechanism detect that the other side is not ACKnowledging its packets.

Therefore, if the client application expects to be "listening" most of the time, it may be convenient to implement a keep alive system that works "both ways" as Stephen Clearly explains in the link you posted. But, this keep alive system would be part of your application layer, rather than part of the transport layer as ping/pongs.

For example you can have a message "{token:'whatever'}" that the server and client just echoes with a 5 seconds delay. The client should have a timer with a 10 seconds timeout that stops every time that messages is received and starts every time the message is echoed, if the timer triggers, the connection can be consider dropped.